# Последовательное чередование символов в строке

Tags: python, linux, perl

Строки разной произвольной длины, различные символы. Как выполнить сдвиг символов строки на один символ и  последовательно перебрать все варианты, чтобы на выходе из строки `1a2b3c` получить:

```
1a2b3c
a2b3c1
2b3c1a
b3c1a2
3c1a2b
c1a2b3
```

Требуется включить подобный скрипт в трубе в терминале средствами Unix ToolBox, Python, Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На Питоне:

```
import collections

dq = collections.deque("1a2b3c")

for __ in range(len(dq)):
    print("".join(dq))
    dq.rotate(-1)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1a2b3c
> a2b3c1
> 2b3c1a
> b3c1a2
> 3c1a2b
> c1a2b3
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

[Объекты типа `deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (*double queue - двойная очередь, очередь с двумя концами*) имеют метод `rotate()` (*вращай*), который делает точно то, что вы хотите, когда его параметр `-1`.
(Положительные числа - вращение вправо, отрицательные - вращение влево.)

Так что `dq` содержит одиночные символы заданной строки, нужно их перед печатей превратить в строку (`"".join()`).

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "1a2b3c"
for _ in range(len(s)):
    print(s)
    s = s[1:] + s[0]

1a2b3c
a2b3c1
2b3c1a
b3c1a2
3c1a2b
c1a2b3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val = '1a2b3c'

[ val[i:len(val)]+val[0:i] for i in range(len(val))]

['1a2b3c', 'a2b3c1', '2b3c1a', 'b3c1a2', '3c1a2b', 'c1a2b3']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;

my @chars = qw(1 a 2 b 3 c);
# OR
# my $s = '1a2b3c' # или из любого источника;
# my @chars = split //, $s;
while(1) {
    say @chars;
    push @chars, shift @chars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $str = '1a2b3c';
my $len = length($str) -1;
    for(0..$len){
    $str =~ s/(.)(.{$len})/$2$1/;
    print "$str\n"; 
    }
```

```
a2b3c1
2b3c1a
b3c1a2
3c1a2b
c1a2b3
1a2b3c
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
echo "a1b2c3" | xargs -i@ bash -c 'seq $(($(expr length @-))) | sed -z "s/[0-9]*\n/@/g;s/$/\n/" | grep -oE .{$(($(expr length @-)))}'
```

Работает не совсем корректно:

```
a1b2c3a
1b2c3a1
b2c3a1b
2c3a1b2
c3a1b2c
3a1b2c3
```

Answer (score 0):

Oldscool style :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$chars = '1a2b3c';
my @chars = split(//,$chars);
$\="\n";
foreach $i (@chars){
    print @chars;
    push @chars, shift @chars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант Perl => С использованием функции substr():

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$chars = '1a2b3c';
$\="\n";
for (my $i=0;$i<length($chars);$i++){
    print $chars = substr($chars,1).substr($chars,0,1);
}
```

Вывод:

```
a2b3c1
2b3c1a
b3c1a2
3c1a2b
c1a2b3
1a2b3c
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl с использованием regex (уже было но можно попроще):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$chars = '1a2b3c';
$\="\n";
for (my $i=0;$i<length($chars);$i++){
    $chars=~s/(.)(.+)/\2\1/;
    print $chars;
}
```

Вывод аналогичен.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
s = "1a2b3c"
for i in range(len(s)):
    s=print(s) or s[1:]+s[:1]
```

Или одной строкой:

```
print([(s[i+1:len(s)]+s[0:i+1]) for i in range(len(s))])
```